# How can I print in console a formatted sparse matrix with eigen?

Tags: eigen

I am working with Eigen [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html). I have a sparse Matrix defined by a set of Triplet and I would like to print the Matrix in a formatted way. I have seen that it is possible with ordinary Matrix by doing Matrix.format(FORMAT_TYPE) [Eigen: IOFormat](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/structEigen_1_1IOFormat.html). But i do not find a way to do the same for sparse Matrix. I would like to obtain an output like the Matlab output for matrices.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `std::cout << m << "\n";`?

Comment: yes but the values are not correted tabulated ... could it depends on visual studio?

Comment: What do you mean not tabulated? It prints some other stuff before the matrix? If that's what you mean, run it in release, not debug.

Comment: I obtain this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzZq8JcubzXoMHdLTVRCSXJlYm8) but i want this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzZq8JcubzXoMXZPTjZfMUh6Mkk)

Answer (score 3):

To get nice formatting, you need to first convert it to a dense matrix:

```
SparseMatrix<double> spmat;
...
std::cout << MatrixXd(spmat) << std::endl;
```

Comment: @ggael That would require allocating the entire NxM matrix, no?

Comment: yes, but usually you only output rather small matrices for debugging

Answer (score 1):

Probably not of interest for the OP anymore, but I came here via Google and so others will maybe too...

It's not pratical to print the whole sparse matrix directly, because they are usually very big. The [block operator](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html) works for sparse also, so you can do something like:

```
int nElements = 10;
std::cout <<
compMat.block( compMat.rows() - nElements, compMat.cols() - nElements, nElements, nElements )
          << std::endl;
```

to print the last 10 elements in the bottom right corner of a square sparse matrix.

This takes 6ms in release mode on my machine.

The following code does the same on the full matrix with roughly 35000*35000 entries, but takes ~25000ms...

```
int nElements = 10;
std::cout <<
Eigen::MatrixXd( compMat ).block( compMat.rows() - nElements, compMat.cols() - nElements, nElements,
                                               nElements )
          << std::endl;
```